# Nonlinear method to solve an equation with the error function in it

Tags: special-functions, nonlinear-optimization, error-function

My question is to find a method to solve the following non-linear equation. I know it should be an iterative method, but I don't know what would be the best method to use. Any help is highly appreciated.

erf(x) + a*x = b ; where both a and b are constants.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using a computer and have the tools to evaluate semi-complicated expressions involving the error function.  If so, simply use Newton's method and iterate

$$
n(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = 
x-\frac{a x-b+\text{erf}(x)}{a+\frac{2
   e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}}
$$

For example, if $a=2$ and $b=1$, then starting at $x=1.0$, you'll generate the sequence

$$1.0, 0.237011, 0.322921, 0.323604, 0.323604.$$

Alternatively, if you've just got a few cases to solve, you could [enter it into WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20erf%28x%29%2b2x=1):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. Can I extend my question like this: What if x is now a vector of (N by 1) and A is a matrix of (N by N) and b is also a vector of (N by 1). This follows the non-linear equation:

erf(x) + A*x = b

I am confused in isolating the term x from the combined term A*x so that I can apply Newton's method on this. Any ideas? Thanks again for your prompt reply.